# Empty string taking precedence in python regex subpatterns with multiple groups

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

As I understand, `|` tries different subpatterns in alternation and matches the first possible option. Whenever there are multiple groups, the later ones behave unexpectedly when one of the subpatterns is empty giving it priority.

Example: `re.search("(ab|a|).*(as|a|).*(qwe|qw|)", "abcde asdfg qwerty").groups()` returns: `('ab', '', '')`.

If the empty option is removed `re.search("(ab|a|).*(as|a).*(qwe|qw)", "abcde asdfg qwerty").groups()` The result is `('ab', 'as', 'qwe')` as expected.

I am interested in a way to achieve the second result and be able to match a string like `abc qwerty` and obtain `('ab', '', 'qwe')` or `abcd asd` and obtain `('ab', 'as', '')`.

The explanation on why the patterns did not work as I expected will be appreciated, but it is not my main concern. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.match('^(ab|a|)\w*\s*(?:(as|a)\w*|)\w*?\s*(qwe|qw|)',s) #s is your string
```

this is the best that I was able to come up with. As Kenneth K. stated, there is a kind of trivial combination of greedy tokens and non-greedy tokens while matching empty matches. The work around for that was to not use `.*`, which so easily just eats everything in its path. instead, this will essentially look for the next word and match if possible, and just pass if it cant.

The only difference between what you want and what I have SHOULD be that instead of a blank string, if the second one (the 'as|a') string is not there, the object will be `None` rather than `''` but you can probably work around that

Tests:

```
>>> s = 'abasdf asdf qwert'
>>> re.match('^(ab|a|)\w*\s*(?:(as|a)\w*|)\w*?\s*(qwe|qw|)',s).groups()
('ab', 'as', 'qwe')
>>> s = 'abab asf qwert'
>>> re.match('^(ab|a|)\w*\s*(?:(as|a)\w*|)\w*?\s*(qwe|qw|)',s).groups()
('ab', 'as', 'qwe')
>>> s = 'abab qwert'
>>> re.match('^(ab|a|)\w*\s*(?:(as|a)\w*|)\w*?\s*(qwe|qw|)',s).groups()
('ab', None, 'qwe')
>>> s = 'abab asfq'
>>> re.match('^(ab|a|)\w*\s*(?:(as|a)\w*|)\w*?\s*(qwe|qw|)',s).groups()
('ab', 'as', '')
```

you can also use `re.match('^(ab|a|)\w*\s*(?:(as|a)\w*|)\w*?\s*(?:(qwe|qw)\w*|)',s).groups()` if you want the third element to turn up `None` if not there as well.

NOTE: I don't think this will work if you want to match a as or qwe word as the first word. I'm still trying to work on that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're getting that middle group is the `.*` is greedy. It sees all characters in your string and consumes all of them.

You probably want something like this:

`(ab|a|).* ?(as|a|).* (qwe|qw|)`

It might be more helpful if you posted exactly what you need.  I'm not sure what the use case of this might be, and if there is a better way to write that regex.

Comment: I don't think greediness is the sole contributor, though. Removing the greediness (`(ab|a|).*?(as|a|).*?(qwe|qw|)`) yields the same result.

Comment: @Kenneth K. you're right, it's not simply the greediness of the `.*` It also has to do with the implicit laziness of regex, where it will only search up to the last character it needs to to fulfill the match.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your issue is a combination of greediness and the empty token. The reason why is that when the pattern starts out, it will happily match the `ab` at the beginning of the string. So the first token is satisfied. Now the next token is the greedy dot. This consumes all of the remaining characters in your target string. This satisfies that token. The next token is an alternation. Neither of the first two options can be matched since you are at the end of the target string thanks to the greedy dot. However, the empty token can trivially match. This satisfies that entire group. The next token is another greedy dot. However, this dot requires **zero** or more occurrences of any character. Since you are at the end of the string (because of the first greedy dot), this token is trivially satisfied. The final token has the same behavior and result as the previously described group. So again, this final token is trivially satisfied.